# Строить tab динамически или скрывать вкладки?

Tags: c#

Есть `tabControl`, на нем 3 вкладки 1 используется всегда 2 нет, как лучше сделать скрывать 2 вкладки когда не нужно или строить сам `tab` динамически?
`tab` находится в новом форме, поэтому каждый раз при открытие создается заново.

Comment: Сколько данных отображается в табах? Это dataGrid'ы с кучей строк или просто несколько контролов накидано?

Comment: @Drac5,в одном куча label, но они создаются динамически и пару картинок, в другом штук 10 label и изображение, а третий показуется постоянно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если действительно не так много данных и их количество не меняется после открытия формы, то я предлагаю не заморачиваться и заполнять все табы при открытии формы.

Если вдруг содержимое одного из табов зависит от данных в других табах, то имеет смысл обновлять табы динамически.

Comment: табы зависят от содержимого выбранного из списка файла. буду делать динамически. спасибо.